# Flask doesn't update the site as it should

Tags: python, flask

I am making a website for scraping. Once the user clicks start scraping the pages shows a flash "Scraping started".

The code for this route is the following:

```
@app.route('/scrape', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def scrape():
    form = ScrapingForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        city = request.form.get('city')
        subregion = request.form.get('subregion')
        apart_or_house = request.form.get('apart_or_house')
        words_to_check = request.form.get('words_to_check')

        if city and apart_or_house:
            session['scraping_started'] = True  # Set session variable
            g.scraping_finished = False
            threading.Thread(target=run_scraper, args=(city, subregion, apart_or_house, words_to_check)).start() 
            flash('Scraping started!', 'success')
        else:
            flash('Please fill all required fields.', 'error')

    return render_template('scrape.html', form=form)
```

As you can see this route call the function run_scraper which looks like this:

```
def run_scraper(city, subregion, apart_or_house, words_to_check):
# ...rest of the code

    subprocess.run(['python', 'test_file.py'])

    with app.app_context():
        return redirect(url_for('scraping_finished'))
```

Now this function call a python file by the given name. The python file opens and executes normally. After that it should redirect the page to the route 'scraping_finished'.

I have set up the route for that, and checked that it works manually

```
@app.route('/scraping-finished')
def scraping_finished():
    return render_template('scraping_finished.html')
```

and here is scraping_finished.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Scraping finished</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .title-margin-top {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2 class="title-margin-top text-center">Scraping finished</h2>
                <a href="{{ url_for('scrape') }}" class="btn btn-primary d-block mx-auto">Return to Scraping</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-6 (run_scraper):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 1052, in _bootstrap_inner    
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 989, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\xxxxx\xxxxx\Documents\Python\German website\app.py", line 98, in run_scraper
    return redirect(url_for('scraping_finished'))
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 222, in url_for
    return current_app.url_for(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1040, in url_for
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Unable to build URLs outside an active request without 'SERVER_NAME' configured. Also configure 'APPLICATION_ROOT' and 'PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME' as needed.
```

How do I resolve the issue so that the when the execution of the python file is over, it redirects the page to scraping_finished.html?